# update controller variable and use it in view from directive (angular 1.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to update a controller variable from a child directive.
I updated controller variable but this value doesn't change in the view.
Need I use $scope.$apply() ? $digest ?

this is my code http://plnkr.co/edit/zTKzofwjPfg9eXmgmi8s?p=preview

js file

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('parentController', function($scope) {
    this.myVar = 'Hello from parent';

    this.refreshMyVar = function(data) {
        this.myVar = data.name;
        console.log('>> this.myVar', this.myVar);
    };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="file" />',
        bindToController: {
            attrFromParent: '='
        },
        controller: 'directiveController as directiveCtrl',
        link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
            el.bind('change', function(e) {
              ctrl.onChange(e.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('directiveController', function() {
    this.onChange = function(file) {
        this.attrFromParent(file);
    };
});
```

html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="parentController as parentCtrl">
  <h1> >> {{parentCtrl.myVar}}</h1>
  <p><my-directive attr-from-parent="parentCtrl.refreshMyVar" /></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

if you have other proposition to make my code clean, share it please

## UPDATE

```
app.controller('parentController', function($scope) {
    this.myVar = 'Hello from parent';

    this.refreshMyVar = data => {
        this.myVar = data.name;
        console.log('>> this.myVar', this);
        $scope.$parent.$apply(); // solve my problem
    };
});
```

$scope.$parent.$apply(); but I'm not very satisfied, if someone have other proposition

Comment: First you have written my-directive element syntax wrong. It should not an self-closing element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `my-directive` element syntax is wrong. It should not be a self-closing element that is not a valid HTML.

Syntax should be as following

```
<my-directive attr-from-parent="parentCtrl.refreshMyVar"></my-directive>
```

Second and important

```
app.controller('parentController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.myVar = 'Hello from parent';
    this.refreshMyVar = function(data) {
      // You should not directly refer "this" inside refreshMyVar function 
      // since "refreshMyVar" function is executed in context of directive 
      // "this" will refer "myDirective" controller scope
      // console.log("this :" this); // try to uncomment and see what "this" holds
      // If you use "vm" you will be able to get hold of actual "myVar" due to
      // closure formed by refreshMyVar function when it was created.
      // console.log("vm :" vm); // try to uncomment and see what "vm" holds
      // Reading about closures(JavaScript concept) will help you.
      vm.myVar = data.name;
      console.log(vm);
      alert('>> this.myVar ' + vm.myVar);
      // Since refreshMyVar is executed in context of directive, you have do
      // $apply on parent scope to apply changes
      $scope.$parent.$apply();
    };
});
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fiLq3M8CxiGd9JUyX6R6?p=preview)

This [article](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) may also help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the code that I posted was just an example but when a I code, I'm using ES6,

```
this.refreshMyVar = data => {
 this.myVar = data.name;
 console.log('>> this.myVar', this);
 $scope.$parent.$apply();
};
```

So $scope.$parent.$apply(); solve my problem